# Use internal speakers while headphones are plugged in to iPod touch 5th generation

Tags: ipod-touch, audio, headphones, speakers

An audio plug that was used to connect to speakers is stuck in the audio jack of my iPod touch 5th generation and I can't get it out.

Is there a way to change the settings so I can only use the internal speakers, or is there an app that would let me switch to using internal speakers even though headphones are plugged in?

Comment: What os do you have, what version of audio midi player, what settings do you have in your sounds?

Answer (score 1):

No. Only if you remove the object and the switch that detects the object resets to the normal position will the internal speaker option come back.

See these threads for more details.

- [Why are my Macbook's internal speakers not available?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8820/why-are-my-macbooks-internal-speakers-not-available)
- [Use internal speakers with others plugged in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6510/use-internal-speakers-with-others-plugged-in)